# Did Google Maps API just retire the "dragdir" parameter?

Tags: google-maps

The API i've been using for years for driving direction data seems to be failing as of this morning:
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=41.029598,28.972985&daddr=41.033586,28.984546&output=dragdir

Just wondering if anyone knows about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it does not work... then I guess... yea...? lol

Sorry.

But, you should switch to the *Google Maps API Web Services* [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). In which you can get a JSON respond by calling [this URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.029598,28.972985&destination=41.033586,28.984546):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=41.029598,28.972985&destination=41.033586,28.984546
```